# C++ - multi-dimensional arrays and variable lengths?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

So, I am dealing with a code base where we are attempting to merge several code bases into one neat stack. I'm running into trouble with the BYTE arrays that we use. Our stuff is based around communication via byte arrays, and so each of our apps stores the messages it needs to send like so:

```
BYTE arr[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02};
```

So now, I am smashing all the arrays together into arrays of arrays to try to group them together, like so:

```
BYTE groupOneArrs[][15] = 
{
   {0x01, 0x02, 0x03},
};

BYTE groupTwoArrs[][15] = 
{
   {0xFF, 0xA9, 0xAA},
};
```

And etc. However, I am running into issues, because the sizes of the individual messages must be preserved, because in order for the messages to be considered valid, they must be the same lengths that we defined them as. I got around this by defining an int array with the actual lengths of each element, but it's dirty. Is there an easier way to store these 2D arrays, which will preserve the lengths of each individual array?

EDIT: So it's sounding like I'm SOL with VS 2008 and variable-length 2D arrays in the header files. Is there a way I could work around this with, say, a struct? something like

```
struct Message{
   byte message[20];
   int size;
}
```

And then initialize it like...

```
Message messages[] = {
   {{0x01, 0x02, 0x03}, 3},
};
```

Well, I should say, I tried something like this, and it blew up. But something like that, anyway. I just don't want to have to make variable names for each array just to preserve the size, that just seems silly.

Comment: A [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? Should work very well with the new initializer lists in C++11.

Comment: I am stuck on Visual Studio 2008, but vectors might help. I am definitions my arrays in a common header file since they take up so much space - can I simply initialize the vectors from within it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making 2D array, use **adjacency list**. `vector` should be the best for this purpose. They come handy in forming adjacency lists.

Comment: if I initialize a vector as vector<BYTE*>, how do I keep track of the lengths of the individual arrays?

Comment: Not vector<Byte *>. Make vector of vector<Byte> i.e  vector<vector<Byte> >.

Comment: OK, but how do I initialize it without it getting crazy? It's sounding like I'm going to have to split all my byte arrays into individual arrays in my header file, so I can add them to a vector, one byte at a time, in my cpp file. This is starting to sound like a lot of code.